# Syncing photos in Android gallery

Tags: android, android-gallery, android-image

I've seen a few apps that can sync photos with the Android gallery (such as Picasa), and I'm wanting to create something similar myself, where I would have a remote server with the photos and the users would be able to access these from within separate albums in the gallery (as the aforementioned apps). However, I do not know how this could be achieved, or even where do begin.

Does anyone know how I should go about doing this?

---

[image: Screenshot]
*My Facebook photos in the synced stock gallery app on my Galaxy Note 10.1*

Comment: Did you ever found a solution to your problem?