# How to get an application listed in android Gallery

Tags: android, android-gallery

I am developing an android application that offers images to the user so that they can be manipulated.

The application also has an image pool of the manipulated images.

My intention is to have these images listed in the android built-in gallery and I would like that the application be recognized by the gallery just as facebook or Picasa. Basically would like to be listed here.

A similar (and I think related) question was asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14906081/syncing-photos-in-android-gallery) but it has no answers.

[image]

What do i have to code in order to achieve this?